# Get selected value from select tag

Tags: javascript

When I select a value from the option and click on a button, I want to fetch the selected value with javascript. What am I doing wrong? My value is always 1.

```
 <select id="aand_select">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
```

// javascript code

```
var e = document.getElementById("aand_select");
var quantity= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Why don't you use `e.value` instead?

Comment: still value is 1 when I select 5 for example

Comment: Works on my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QPvHL/

Comment: And `e.value` works too if I edit your fiddle. I must say: obviously.

Comment: @AndrejHefner Are you sure that `<select>` is the only element with id "aand_select"?
Maybe there's another one before and that's what `document.getElementById` gets.

Answer (score 3):

This apparently will do

```
var e = document.getElementById("aand_select");
e.addEventListener('change', function(){
  var quantity= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(quantity);
},false);​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are calling the javascript at the appropriate time. For example if you are calling it only when the page loads, the value will never change. Make sure you are calling it from an onClick() or some other event.

Comment: the function starts when a button is clicked

Comment: Can you post the source of your page? We may be able to notice something that is missing.